# Sysinternal's VMMap is unable to find injected memory

Tags: windows, virtual-memory, sysinternals

I'm writing a Python script that uses the Windows API to learn process injection.

The injection is successful. I can verify that the shellcode is running, and Process Explorer shows the connection:

[image: Process Explorer]

The problem is, when I looked for the injected memory region using VMMap, I am unable to find it. The output of my program indicates what the virtual address of the allocated memory region was. In the example case, the output is:

```
Remote memory address: 0x57c0000
```

When I open the process in VMMap, click the "Total", and then sort the bottom panel by address however,

[image: VMMap]

It's mysteriously missing. Is there a reason it's missing, assuming the address the program reports is correct (which, it's coming straight from the Windows API, so it should be)?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out, I neglected to run VMMap as an administrator, which caused some regions to be missed. If I reopen it with elevated privileges, I'm able to find it:

[image: Found VMMap]

So if you're unable to find a region of memory, make sure you have the proper permissions.